# Are there any "captain's men" in the Mirror Universe?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-eu, mirror-universe

In the *Star Trek* mirror universe, there are often "captain's women", who provide companionship to male captains. Notably, we have [Marlena Moreau](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Marlena_Moreau_(mirror)), who served Kirk, and [Hoshi Soto](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hoshi_Sato_(mirror)), who served both Forrest and Archer.

Are there any "captain's men" who are male counterparts who similarly serve female captains (or perhaps non-heterosexual male captains)?

I'm open to any level of *Star Trek* canon.

Comment: Well, there is http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Ezri_Tigan_(mirror) .

Comment: @BCdotWEB That says that Ezri Tigan is female. I'm looking for males.

Comment: Does [Benjamin Sisko](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Benjamin_Sisko_(mirror)) count?  Though I suppose technically Kira wasn't a captain.

Answer (score 3):

When Michael Burnham is captain of the ISS Shenzhou, we see Ash Tyler take on a similar role and the crew treating him similarly. Though I think officially he was there as her bodyguard.